# Entity Framework alter column type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, migration, entity

I have created a column in my database using this property:

```
public int EnteredDateTime { get; set; }
```

The column is created correctly, however, when I update the property:

```
public DateTime EnteredDateTime { get; set; }
```

I am getting the following error:

`The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use CodeFirst to generate the DB?

Comment: _Where_ do you get the error?

Comment: Yes I have used the Code First , how to set the default value within property ?

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if you forgot to set the property.

The default value for a `DateTime` is `1/1/0001`, which is outside the range of SQL Server dates.

Comment: how to set the default value within property ?

Comment: @Gaurav: Set it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have used CodeFirst to generate the DB. You currently can't just change the code and automatically alter the DB (this will be possible in EF 5 via Migrations). You have to manually alter the DB and set the type of the column to DateTime. Or you you delete and recreate the DB from scratch (if you don't need the data that is already stored in it).

Comment: I have enabled the migrations and it is working fine for other type changes other than DateTime.

Comment: Did you check the data type of the column in the DB is it correct? EF 5 is still in beta it might have bugs...

Comment: Well DB had int and I changed to DateTime but it didn't change in DB.

Comment: Then alter the column type manually, might be a bug of EF 5 beta.